# How do I implement a transition animation in React?

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs

I have a React component that displays multiple pages of content. Clicking buttons elsewhere in the application should change what this component displays, with a given transition. This transition is a custom Javascript transition, and not a CSS one, so I can't use [ReactCSSTransitionGroup](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html).

There are two approaches I can think of. Both involve passing in the `transition` as a prop, but differ on how the next page is passed into the component.

## Option A

This option uses the presence of the `transition` prop to indicate that it should animate. It keeps `page1` in it's internal `state` so that it can still render it until the transition is complete. When it completes the component dispatches an action that causes the parent component to remove the transition prop.

Each of the steps is another render of the `Pager` component by a parent component.

```
// 1
<Pager currentPage={page1} />
// 2
<Pager currentPage={page2} transition={transition} />
// 3
<Pager currentPage={page2} />
```

## Option B

This option passes in both the `transition` and the `nextPage` explicitly. Again the component dispatches an action when the transition is complete.

```
// 1
<Pager currentPage={page1} />
// 2
<Pager currentPage={page1} nextPage={page2} transition={transition} />
// 3
<Pager currentPage={page2} />
```

I'm not sure which of these is better, or if there is a completely different approach that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

## Option C

The page should know how to run transition, and notify the parent when its done. This way you'll get a very simple API like this

```
// Not pages.. page
<Page
  transition={{...}}
  component={Login}
  onTransitionEnd={...}
/>
```

So you can run two transitions at the same time, like opening Page1 and closing Page2

You could built a wrapper like `<Pager />` around the pages, to make the calculations inside for the next transition in place.

```
<Pager initIndex={0} pages={[....]}>
```

But the `<Page />` itself should know how to *move*